# Changing loglevel in appsettings.json won't get applied to NLog

Tags: c#, .net-core, nlog

I am using NLog with dotnet core app configured like described here. https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2

In nlog.config if I set minLevel to Error and launch my app I can see on logger that logDebug is disabled.

If I restore back to trace then all levels are set to true `(error, trace, debug, info, warning)`

and if I put this into config file (appsettings.json)

```
"Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Error",
            "Microsoft": "Information"
        }
    }
```

then nothing happens, all logger levels are still set to true, what might be wrong ? 
[image]

Comment: You are showing the debug-details for the pure NLog Logger-object, but you have configured the Microsoft Extension Logging (MEL) LoggerFactory. NLog doesn't know about configuration of MEL-filters. MEL-ILogger will perform filtering according MEL-config (and forward to NLog-provider if added). NLog-Logger will perform filtering according to NLog-config.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Snakefoot mentioned,

this is the config of Microsoft Extension Logging.

When using NLog + Injected .NET Core loggers (using Microsoft Extension Logging), the flow is as follows:

`ILogger<MyClass>` → `LoggerFactory` in Microsoft Extension Logging → `LogFactory` in NLog.

To configure NLog, you should update the NLog `<rules>` in your nlog.config, e.g.

(also possible from code, see [docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API))

```xml
<rules>
   <logger name="*" minlevel="debug" />
</rules>
```

Please note that you won't see debug logs if the minlevel is "debug" in NLog and "error"
the appsettings.json

note 2:
When using  NLog direct, e.g. the `NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()`, you only need to configure NLog and the appsettings.json config isn't used for those logs.

Comment: Sorry its not clear for me: NLog uses Microsoft.Extension.Logging and Microsoft.Extension.Logging is reading log levels from appsettings.json right? so shouldn't appsettings.json be the place where you configure log level? It clearly doesn't work, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @gyozokudor Maybe check this exampe? https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/tree/dev/examples/ASP.NET%20Core%203/ASP.NET%20Core%203%20-%20VS2019

Comment: The link at the github is no longer working. Use this one - https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/tree/master/examples/ASP.NET%20Core%203/ASP.NET%20Core%203%20-%20VS2019